# Spark job execution time

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-1.5

This might be a very simple question. But is there any simple way to measure the execution time of a spark job (submitted using `spark-submit`)?

It would help us in profiling the spark jobs based on the size of input data.

EDIT : I use `http://[driver]:4040` to monitor my jobs, but this Web UI shuts down the moment my job finishes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every SparkContext launches its own instance of Web UI which is available at

> http://[master]:4040
>   by default (the port can be changed using  `spark.ui.port` ).

It offers pages (tabs) with the following information:

Jobs, Stages, Storage (with RDD size and memory use) 
 Environment, Executors, SQL

This information is available only until the application is running by default.

**Tip** : You can use the web UI after the application is finished by enabling `spark.eventLog.enabled`.

Sample web ui  where you can see the time as 3.2hours:
[image]

Comment: thanks, I was going to ask about keeping the information after the job ends, but you have answered it anyway. The `spark.eventLog.enabled` is a configuration parameter specified on the command line while submitting the spark job, correct?

Comment: Yes you are right. For example : ./bin/spark-submit --name "My app" --master local[4] --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=false
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" myApp.jar

Answer (score 1):

SPARK itself provides much granular information about each stage of your Spark Job. Go to the Web interface of Spark on http://your-driver-node:4040, you can use also history server.

If you just need execution time, then go to "http://your-driver-node:8080", and you can see execution time for a job submitted to a spark.

Comment: You can check following url: - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

Comment: I use the `http://your-driver-node:4040` to monitor my jobs always, but it doesn't give me end to end execution time, does it? if yes, then where... I will check the second link though! thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to access 8080 and I don't see it documented...would you have more info about this 8080 page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can write a piece of code to get the net execution time.

**Example:**

```
val t1 = System.nanoTime //your first line of the code

val duration = (System.nanoTime - t1) / 1e9d //your last line of the code
```